# question about asp.net lifecycle

Tags: c#, asp.net, lifecycle

how can i programmatically restart page lifecycle? i do some stuff in controls events which affects these controls. to see changes i have to draw page again. how can i do it?

Comment: The only way to restart the page lifecycle would be to do a Response.Redirect back to the page. You would, of course, then lose any of the changes you had made, so this is a pointless answer. However, you should not have to restart the page lifecycle to affect how controls look... For example, you can change the text of a label in a button's Click event, so you should be able to change your controls wherever you need to. What exactly are you trying to change?

Comment: i'm filling Table with fields from another Table.

Comment: I guess you have to find the correct "point in time" to fill your *one* table with the values from your *other table*. For this to work, you need to understand the page life cycle of ASP.NET (e.g. by reading Microsoft's description: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx -> ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview). And be aware that the life cycle is slightly different for non post backs opposed to post backs. In general I think you might want to do this in PreRender.

Answer (score 1):

The page will be "re-drawn" near the end of the page lifecycle, during the Render phase.  Remember that immediately after this happens, this instance of your page is destroyed.  That is the nature of the web.  The page lifecycle will re-start when the user triggers a postback in their browser.  At this point, a brand new instance of your page class is created.  This new instance will strongly resemble the previous instance, but it's still a completely different instance of the class.  This is how ASP.Net works.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
Response.Redirect(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath);
```

but you may lose your drawing if you don't save it somewhere on server or client (e.g. cookie)